# How do I prevent Google Analytics from sending cookies to cookie-less subdomains?

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, cookie

I'm trying to keep GA from setting cookies on static files like images. All the files concerned are loaded from cookie-free subdomains. Is there a way to exclude these subdomains from getting the cookie that is set by Google Analytics?

Comment: Is there a tracking code on some of the pages on these subdomains, or are you just finding cookies there?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller they're not pages, just images, css files and the like. GA is still sending cookies to them though.

Comment: What is your cookie domain set to in your GA snippet?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller auto, which AFAIK should default to the top domain and ignore the subdomains.

Comment: Any cookies set at the top domain will show up on subdomains.  I assume that your site is on www?  If so you need to set the domain in your ga snippet to include the www.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller ah, that does make some sense. Thanks.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller and for future readers: disabling google analytics entirely does not stop the any of the popular optimisation tools from reporting the static files as coming from a cookie setting domain. It appears that the analysis tools are flagging the static files regardless of whether they actually set cookies of not.